# Scaling hotkey S no longer works in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, shortcut

Suddenly, when pressing the S hotkey in edit mode, scaling is not working.  It was working previously, and still works in other modes, like Object mode and UV Editor.  I am new to Blender, so maybe I hit something and changed it?  I am using Blender 2.93.4.  I tried a new file, the default cube did the same thing.  I tried preferences keymap, but am not exactly sure what to change to fix it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you please share your file or at least show a screenshot? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I fixed it, apparently something had gotten switched in the keymap.  I tried restoring the 3D view settings, but there was a second restore option for the mesh category, and that fixed it.  Thanks though.